# RegEx for Client-Side Validation of FileUpload

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, symbols

I'm trying to create a RegEx Validator that checks the file extension in the FileUpload input against a list of allowed extensions (which are user specified). The following is as far as I have got, but I'm struggling with the syntax of the backward slash (`\`) that appears in the file path. Obviously the below is incorrect because it just escapes the (`]`) which causes an error. I would be really grateful for any help here. There seems to be a lot of examples out there, but none seem to work when I try them.

```
[a-zA-Z_-s0-9:\]+(.pdf|.PDF)$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include a backslash in a character class, you need to use a specific escape sequence (`\b`):

```
[a-zA-Z_\s0-9:\b]+(\.pdf|\.PDF)$
```

Note that this might be a bit confusing, because outside of character classes, `\b` represents a word boundary. I also assumed, that `-s` was a typo and should have represented a white space. (otherwise it shouldn't compile, I think)

**EDIT:** You also need to escape the dots. Otherwise they will be meta character for **any** character but line breaks.

**another EDIT:** If you actually DO want to allow hyphens in filenames, you need to put the hyphen at the end of the character class. Like this:

```
[a-zA-Z_\s0-9:\b-]+(\.pdf|\.PDF)$
```

Comment: OK! And there was me thinking I was close!!! Thank you so much for all your help. I will give it a whirl now.

Comment: @user470249 If it solves your problem, the best way to say thanks for an answer is accepting it, and possibly an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9\s:\\-]+\.[pP][dD][fF]$
```

which is same as

```
[\w\s:\\-]+\.[pP][dD][fF]$
```

because `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Be sure character `-` to put as very first or very last item in the `[...]` list, otherwise it has special meaning for range or characters, such as `a-z`.

Also `\` character has to be escaped by another slash, even inside of `[...]`.